# Compiling cpp files in one directory into another directory

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

Trying to compile all .cc files in folder called P18298_ca.sub into .exe files in P18298_ca.cmp. I compile using make command from the directory that contains both the source and the target directories. Make error reads:

make: *** No rule to make target `P18298_ca.cmp/00a5bffb6a4792d7bcaed90ff6d3ca88-WA.exe', needed by`main.exe'.  Stop.

Here is the makefile code that I used

```
    CPP_FILES := $(wildcard P18298_ca.sub/*.cc)
    OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst P18298_ca.sub/%.cc,P18298_ca.cmp/%.exe,$(CPP_FILES))
    LD_FLAGS := ...
    CC_FLAGS := ...

    main.exe: $(OBJ_FILES)
        g++ $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

    obj/%.exe: src/%.cc
        g++ $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0):

A binary is built from `*.obj` files, not from `*.exe` files. Also the directories in the macros and the default rules must be the same. Change these lines in your Makefile to

```
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst P18298_ca.sub/%.cc,P18298_ca.cmp/%.obj,$(CPP_FILES))

P18298_ca.cmp/%.obj: P18298_ca.sub/%.cc
    g++ $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```